# set overflow TextOverflow.ellipsis text length Flutter

Tags: flutter, overflow

How to set the length of the overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis becuase it truncate the text as you see in img. There is a empty space between the text 'This is the first...' and the nummber  '#1520'. The overflow truncates the text after 'first...' word.

I want that the words 'card now' will be shown in the Row. How to fix it?, thanks

```
 Container(
      color: Colors.grey,
      child: ListTile(
        title: Container(
          child: Row(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
             Flexible(child: Text('This is the first card now its time sad sad sad sads ad sdsadsads dsa dsad asdasdasd', overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)),
               
              Flexible(child: Text('#1520',  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

[image]

I dont want all of my text to be visible, I just want to show some words in one line. If you look at the img, you will see an empty space between the text and the #1520. I want to use overflow and show: This is the first card now.. #1520

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want all of your text to be visible just remove overflow property from the text widget.
2. If you want to limit your text to certain lines then add the maxLines property with overflow. like this

```
child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Flexible(child: Text("This is the first card now its time sad sad sad sads ad sdsadsads dsa dsad asdasdasd", maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,)),
                  Flexible(child: Text("#1520"))
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: I dont want all of my text to be visible, I just want to show some words in one line. If you look at the img, you will see an empty space between the text and the #1520. I want to use overflow and show: This is the first card now.. #1520

Comment: Try removing the Flexible widget on other text with #1520 if it's not necessary. Or use expanded widget and provide flex value. ```  Expanded(
                    flex: 3,
                      child: Text("This is the first card now its time sad sad sad sads ad sdsadsads dsa dsad asdasdasd",
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,)
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                      child: Text("#1520")
                  )```

Comment: Good idea. I used flex in Flexible like this Flexible(flex: 5,child: Text("This is the first card now its time sad sad sad sads ad sdsadsads dsa dsad asdasdasd", overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,))   .. it helped me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour of how Text widget works with overflowing - it will truncate sentences with words if it detects the text width is greater than the width it can take. Because of this, sometimes it will cause the unexpected extra space between the truncated text and the container edge.

Here is a simple solution if you don't mind part of a word is covered:

simply apply `softWrap: false` to your text widget.

```dart
Text(
  'Long long long long long long text text text text text',
  softWrap: false,
  maxLines: 1, 
  overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
)
```